# How to upload total list of phone's contact photo to server using Android?

Tags: android, listview, contactscontract

I am using **ContactsContract** to retrieve phone's contact details along with **Photo**.
And it's working fine. But now I need to upload those list of contact's photos to my server, all at once. How can i do that ?

Any help is appreciated. Please someone help.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to convert the contacts into a JSONArray and use volley JSONArrayRequest to send it to the server.

Comment: I need to upload all the images together using a unique id. Is that possible ?